# Find the PDF of gamma distributed random variable using derivation

Tags: gamma-function, gamma-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable with CDF $F_X(x)$ given by
$$
F_X(x)=1-\frac{\Gamma(m,(m/y)x)}{\Gamma(m)},
$$

where  $m$ and $y$ are positive integers $(m>0, y>0)$ and $\Gamma(a,z)$ is the incomplete gamma function defined 
$$
\Gamma(a,z)=\int_{z}^{\infty}t^{a-1}e^{-t}dt.
$$ 
How we can find the PDF of $X$, $f_X(x)$ using derivation method?.

The PDF of $X$ is given by 
$$
f_X(x)=\frac{m^m}{y^m\Gamma(m)}x^{m-1}e^{-(m/y)x}.
$$

My quetion how to get $f_X(x)$ using 
$$
f_X(x)=\frac{dF_X(x)}{dx}.
$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you, for instance, tried the definition of the derivative (perhaps with [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement))?  If so, how much progress did you make?

Comment: I would like to find the PDF of $X$ using $f_X(x)=\frac{dF_X(x)}{dx}$. Thanks

Comment: You are more likely to get responses if you address the instructions to the right of the box you typed your question into, including "[Provide details.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) Share your research."  Which includes "Include your work".

Comment: Actually, you seem to be merely after the basic differentiation formula $$\frac d{dx}\int_{cx}^\infty g(t)dt=-cg(cx)$$

Comment: OK, this low give the right answer, thanks, could you please provide for me reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 
$$F_X(x)=1-\frac{\Gamma(m,(m/y)x)}{\Gamma(m)},$$
where 
$$\Gamma(a,z) = \int_{z}^{\infty}t^{a-1}e^{-z}dt.$$
Then 
$$f_X(x)=\frac{dF_{X}(x)}{dx} = \frac{-1}{\Gamma(m)}\left(\int_{(m/y)x}^{\infty}t^{m-1}e^{-(m/y)x}dt\right)'.$$
Now 
$$\frac{d\Gamma(a,z)}{dz} = -e^{-z}z^{a-1}$$
and so 
$$f_X(x) = \frac{-1}{\Gamma(m)}\left(\int_{(m/y)x}^{\infty}t^{m-1}e^{-(m/y)x}dt\right)'$$
$$ = \frac{1}{\Gamma(m)}\left[ e^{-(m/y)x}((m/y)x)^{m-1}\right]\frac{m}{y} = \frac{m^m}{y^m\Gamma(m)}x^{m-1}e^{-(m/y)x}.$$

Comment: Please, how did you simplifay $$\frac{-1}{\Gamma(m)}\left(\int_{(m/y)x}^{\infty}t^{m-1}e^{-(m/y)x}dt\right)'$$

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement

Comment: D you mean we first derivation  then integral?

Comment: You want to derivate a function which is written as an integral. You have something like $\Gamma(a,z) = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} G(t,z)dt.$

Comment: ok, just this step $$\frac{-1}{\Gamma(m)}\left(\int_{(m/y)x}^{\infty}t^{m-1}e^{-(m/y)x}dt\right)'$$, could you please add more detail.

Comment: Te problem , wz have $\Gamma(m,cz)$ were $c>0$, if its   $\Gamma(m,z)$, its normal, but when it  $\Gamma(m,cz)$, using $d \Gamma(m,cz)/dz$ we can not obtain the same $f_X(x)$.

Comment: Hi, there is mistake in your  derivation.